# Unity variables reset to zero C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following code:

```
    private float defaultScale;

    public void Start()
    {
        defaultScale = (float)this.transform.localScale.x;
    }
```

The value of defaultScale can be printed in other functions such as

```
    public void increaseSize()
    {
        Debug.Log("Increase Size: " + defaultScale);
        if(!unlocked){
            return;
        }
        GameObject gameObj = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("medical")[0];
        gameObj.transform.localScale += specification/scaling;
    }
```

But it will reset to zero everytime when I call this function:

```
    public void BackToOriginalSize() {
        Debug.Log("Back To Original Size: " + defaultScale);
        if(!unlocked) {
            return;
        }
        GameObject gameObj = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("medical")[0];
        gameObj.transform.localScale *= (defaultScale/gameObj.transform.localScale.x);
        
    }
```

The actual value of 'defaultScale' doesn't change. It is just somehow `BackToOriginalSize` function can't access the value.

I got rid of the last two lines of `BackToOriginalSize` function and also  tried calling it at different times, but all my efforts were unsuccessful.

I was wondering what's wrong with my code.

Comment: What is the behaviour of this and how is that different from the behaviour you want?

Comment: what exactly is `specification/scaling;` ?

Comment: Hi! I would like to get the value of `defaultScale` because I need to use it in my script to scale the object back to its original size. However, this variable gets reset to 0 in this function, but this problem doesn't occur in other functions.

Comment: is `defaultScale` even in the same class? why do you go through `GameObject gameObj = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("medical")[0];`? in the first case you simply use the `this.transform.localScale` ....

Comment: why not rather simply store he original scale as a `Vector3` and later on revert to that

Comment: `specification` is a variable that I declared earlier to indicate how much I want to scale. In this case, `private Vector3 specification = new Vector3(0.05f,0.05f,0.05f);`, which means that I want to scale by 5% each time. `scaling` is something that I do in the `start` function to preprocess the mesh file by scaling it to the size of a unit cube.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really get the calculation or why you first store the original scale of **this** object (`this.transform.localScale`) but later go through `FindGameObjectsWithTag` .. or why you use the multiple objects poll at all if you only want the very first one anyway.

If those aren't in the same class then `defaultScale` might simply be never initialized and keep its default value `0`.

I would simply do something like e.g.

```
private GameObject medical;
private Vector3 originalScale;

private void Start()
{
    medical = GameObject.FindWithTag("medical");
    originalScale = current.transform.localScale;
}

public void increaseSize()
{
    if(!unlocked) return;
      
    medical.transform.localScale += specification/scaling;
}

public void BackToOriginalSize() 
{
    
    if(!unlocked) return;
        
    
    medical.transform.localScale = originalScale;
}
```

Though in general this is probably rather something that should happen in a component of the `medical` object itself

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Unity and C# script. I preprocess the mesh file in the Start function as follows: `scaling = (float) mesh.bounds.size.magnitude/1.73f;` `transform.localScale /= scaling;`. I would like to know how I can save the original size of the mesh in a Vector3 variable.

Comment: @yixjia if you need help with a different problem, ask a new question :)